# Internet of Things using MS Azure

Tags: azure, cloud, iot

I am starting my journey of IoT development with MS Azure. I would like some insight on the Azure cloud. I am a total newbie on cloud development. Can someone tell me some good books/links on Azure that will help me understand how I can use Azure for IoT and start development on the same.?

Thanks a lot for your inputs.

Answer (score 0):

This totally depends on the architecture of your application. You can use SAAS components for rapid prototyping, parts or all of your application architecture. This will give you a better insight into selecting the appropriate stack of tools for your application.

If you want to deploy your own software stack, you would provision Azure Virtual Machines. Azure provides an SDK to interact with the cloud infrastructure.

Docker is a really good option to use for application deployment these days. Google provides better support for Docker containers using its Kubernetes framework.

Simple APIs or website can be developed on azure using Azure webapps. I am currently developing a node application using azure websites. The actual container where the site runs is a windows NT machine with IIS. If you want your SAAS server container's to be linux based then you might look at AWS/Google or Redhat Openshift.

I have used OpenShift SAAS, and found it quite easy to get onboard with.

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to have a look at Build and Ignite events, this week.  There might be more announcements there.  You can definitely have a look at the following white paper: http://download.microsoft.com/download/E/1/F/E1FFDADF-C0FF-4E72-A834-B173A079F393/Microsoft_Internet_of_Things_White_Paper.pdf

The most important services for IoT in Azure are (until today):

- Azure Event Hubs: a massive ingestion service that can take in millions of telemetry events per second.
- Azure Stream Analytics: Real time complex event processing, combining multiple incoming streams of data and detection patterns in it
- PowerBI: this will allow users to build and explore interactive reports and graphs
- Azure Machine Learning: Leverage prediction & machine learning models
- For storage, you have DocumentDB, Azure and blob storage, among other
- HDInsight will help you in working with the data (big data) and make jobs with it.
- Azure Web Apps and API apps will allow you to present and expose the data to you users and custom reports

Good luck